# Installed btlejuice package and can't seem to be able to uninstall it

Tags: software-installation, package-management, kali-linux, npm

I'm using Kali Linux 2020.1 and installed the `btlejuice` package yesterday via the command `npm install -g btlejuice`. Now I'm trying to remove it but when typing `dpkg --list` I can't see it in there. How can I delete it otherwise?

This, of course, means when I try to do `sudo apt-get --purge remove btlejuice` I get an error that the package is not found

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try

```
npm uninstall -g btlejuice
```

because this is not a system package but one installed by a user.

NPM is a package manager for user-level installation of packages, here is some documentation on it: ["About NPM" on `npmjc.com`](https://docs.npmjs.com/about-npm/)

Comment: that actually makes sense, sorry for not figuring it out. I'm however still getting an error: https://imgur.com/a/H5bqWbt

Comment: @Doesitmatter The image link does not work for me. Please add the error message text by editing your question (no image please).

Comment: Managed to solve it using `npm uninstall -g <name> --save`. The error message was about `package.json` files not being found

Comment: @Doesitmatter I added the `-g` option - forgot it earlier. Please try and vote&accept if successful!